# Setting a UITabBarAppearance breaks UITabBarItem appearance proxy font size when selecting tabs

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitabbar, uiappearance

The following, which sets the title text appearance proxy to use a big font, works as expected, and the `UITabBarItem`s retain their big font when you select them:

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        // UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
                
        let bigFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: bigFont], for: .normal)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: bigFont], for: .selected)
        
        return true
    }
```

[image]

But when you set a `UITabBarAppearance` on the `UITabBar` appearance proxy, the font size is broken when you select tabs:

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
                
        let bigFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: bigFont], for: .normal)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font: bigFont], for: .selected)
        
        return true
    }
```

[image]

**Question:**

Does anyone know why setting a `UITabBarAppearance` would break the `setTitleTextAttributes` font size choice?

*Background info:*

The reason I'm using setting the `standardAppearance` on the `UITabBar` is because in my actual project I'm using the following code to retain the old look of the tab bar, and not the new one which goes transparent when there is no content on the screen (and messes up the app design).

If there is a way to achieve that without breaking the font size, then that could be a potential "fix" :)

```swift
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    tabBarAppearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
    UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay I figured out a fix (kinda feels like I'm just using Stack Overflow to [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) at this point ).

The following will retain the correct font size after selecting tabs.

Note it is still necessary to set the attributes directly on the `UITabBarItem` (the `UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes...` lines), because otherwise the tabs won't start with the correct font size, they will only change to it after being selected by the user.

Also note if you're setting the `standardAppearance` on the tab bar, you'll probably also want to set the `scrollEdgeAppearance` - as I did in the last snippet of code in the original question.

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        let bigFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        let textAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: bigFont]
        
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .normal)
        UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(textAttributes, for: .selected)
        
        let tabBarItemAppearance = UITabBarItemAppearance()
        tabBarItemAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
        tabBarItemAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = textAttributes
        
        let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        tabBarAppearance.inlineLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance
        tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance
        tabBarAppearance.compactInlineLayoutAppearance = tabBarItemAppearance
        
        UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
        
        return true
    }
```

Comment: doesn't work at all